# Is replacing icons with emoji a good idea?

Tags: icons, emoji

I'm currently polishing an application I have built using fontawesome. Due to fontawesome's pretty huge (nearly 2 MB with the more accessible SVG + JS Version) footprint, I'm considering to utilize emoji instead. These are already on every machine and users should be used to them.

I think it might be a good idea since using icons the users already associate with their meaning might make it easier for them to quickly understand what a button does, even without reading the associated text. This would be especially good for illiterate, visually impaired or dyslexic users.

There still is the text for screen reader users and the icons are wrapped inside elements that are hidden from them.

The only caveat I can come up with is that [Apple doesn't allow apps that use emoji in their interface sometimes.](https://9to5mac.com/2018/02/02/apple-rejecting-apps-with-emoji/) However this application is company internal and will never show up on any app store so I don't think this would be an issue.

As far as I can tell, all users have OSes that support emoji.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: It is my belief that the quiet among us consider emojis to be the product of a childish generation and look upon such apps with disdain.

Comment: @Rob You are correct in that belief. I have a huge dislike against emoji. However, in the company I work for, emojis are used super commonly and I think I'm alone in being one of the quiet few.

Comment: I feel that emoji's *can* be a good alternative for icons if the application allows it. A business application with emoji-icons will look childish, but a game for example can make it work in some cases.

Comment: @MartijnVissers it depends on the business. We tend to have people commonly replacing words with the emoji for that word in our correspondence. The part that's most important to me is if there are any UX caveats that I have no idea about. If the boss hates how "childish" the UI looks, I can change it back in a few minutes. If there is an accessibility/ usability issue that doesn't come up as quickly, It'll be more difficult to fix + annoy actual users and not just the boss.

Comment: Tempted to type my answer in emojis... 

Comment: Plus using emojis in place of icons is actually  quite complicated from a technical standpoint and might actually represent a much larger payload size than FA at the end of the day. If performance is your main concern find a way to only include a subset of FA.

Comment: @BryceHowitson I know it's out of scope for this site but I'd be really interested in how this would increase payload size. Would you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: I am not an Apple fanboy. In fact I'm an anti-fan and don't own any Apple products. But when their UI guidelines say something like this, you should ask yourself "why". In this case I think they have a good reason for forbidding emoji in UI elements. There are quite a few reasons they are technologically unsuitable and even more cultural and perception issues. If 2MB of UI components is going to break your memory bank, subset it to just the bits you need—but using the wrong tech will induce later headaches a lot harder to solve than 2 MB bloat.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It just is ❌ a ️ .  ️:

- your application will  unprofessional ➕, as someone ️ out, -ish;
- consider users with older systems or machines - they will ❌ be able to  your emojis ➕ might get ;
- often  will misinterpret emojis that their peers ️➡️ to ➡️. ➡️ do ❌  to have a sudden misunderstanding between  ➕ apparently also  emoji like this: ;
- some emojis take a  to guess the meaning of, as opposed to the actual text which users  just ;
- ➕ finally, they are just annoying to  in a non-informal text message environment.

this helps.

**PS: here is the actual text without emojis:**

> It just is not a good idea. See below:
>
> - your application will look unprofessional and, as someone pointed out, child-ish;
> - consider users with older systems or machines - they will not be able to see your emojis and might get confused;
> - often people will misinterpret emojis that their peers send to them. You do not want to have a sudden misunderstanding between OK and
>     apparently also OK emoji like this: Face with OK Gesture;
> - some emojis take a second to guess the meaning of, as opposed to the actual text which users can just read;
> - and finally, they are just annoying to read in a non-informal text message environment.
>
> Hope this helps. smile

Comment: If you have a text with an icon-like emoji next to it, how is that different from using an icon font?

Answer (score 0):

You can use emoji. You could try the open-source Noto Emoji font which is b&w, but using emoji is no different from the colour icons of 10 years ago.